# How to do json data list<T> show dataGridView

Tags: c#, json, list, object, datagridview

I'm using the `Newtonsoft` library for parsing JSON:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

I have my json string and "MyClass" class.

JSON string:

```
{
    "Result":    
            {    
              "MyClassList": [    
                                 {"Id":1,"Amount":"5,00"},    
                                 {"Id":2,"Amount":"10,00"},                                 
                                 {"Id":3,"Amount":"20,00"},    
                                 {"Id":4,"Amount":"25,00"}      
                             ]     
              "ReturnValues":           
                             {
                              "ErrorCode":1,
                              "ErrorDescription":"Successful"
                             }
            } 
}
```

My Class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Amount ")]
    string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting json data using these classes "GetMyClassList", "RootObject" and "ReturnValues".

```
List<MyClass> GetMyClassList()
{
    JObject jo = new JObject();
    List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();
    jo.Add("Name", "Name");
    jo.Add("Surname", "Surname");
    url = "MyUrl";

    string responseText = ExecuteHttpRequest(url , "POST",
             "application/json", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jo.ToString()), 3000);

    myClassList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText)
                   .GetMyClassListResult.MyClassList;

    return myClassList;
}


public class ReturnValues
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
}

public class GetMyClassListResult
{
    [JsonProperty("MyClassList")]
    public List<MyClass> MyClassList { get; set; }
    public ReturnValues ReturnValues { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public GetMyClassListResult GetMyClassListResult { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot get this data array (Id and amount). 
and I want to take this data and show it in a dataGridView.

Comment: I just pasted JSON to the online compiler, there is missing comma ',' behind the array -> is it mistake on the web or is it wrongly returning from the WEB api?

Comment: JSON  data is regular.  I can  show dataGridView "MyClassList" and "ReturnValues"  But I want to see  "Id":1 and "Amount":"5,00" in dataGridView.

Comment: Also `[JsonProperty("Amount ")]` has space after Amount

Comment: Correct in code, I wrote it here..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to t-shoot this is set breakpoint at the line, where u getting the results from method -> is it filled? This Line:

```
return myClassList;
```

I have run Your code with single adjustment -> I have just used the direct JSON (not from web) - code below. This run without issues and I can see all the results parsed out of the JSON.

You have to find if the issue is parsin the JSON, or setting the data to the DataGridTable (which code You have not included at all).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var result = new Program().GetMyClassList();

        foreach (var item in result)
            Console.WriteLine($"ID: {item.Id}\tAmount:{item.Amount}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public List<MyClass> GetMyClassList()
    {
        List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();

        string responseText = "{\"GetMyClassListResult\":{\"MyClassList\":[{\"Id\":1,\"Amount\":\"5,00\"},{\"Id\":2,\"Amount\":\"10,00\"},{\"Id\":3,\"Amount\":\"20,00\"},{\"Id\":4,\"Amount\":\"25,00\"}],\"ReturnValues\":{\"ErrorCode\":1,\"ErrorDescription\":\"Successful\"}}}";

        myClassList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText)
                       .GetMyClassListResult.MyClassList;

        return myClassList;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Amount")]
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}

public class ReturnValues
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
}

public class GetMyClassListResult
{
    [JsonProperty("MyClassList")]
    public List<MyClass> MyClassList { get; set; }
    public ReturnValues ReturnValues { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public GetMyClassListResult GetMyClassListResult { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: myClassList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText)
                       .GetMyClassListResult.MyClassList;   error on this line.  Error :   Additional information: The object reference is not set to the instance of an object.